# Copyright message in code in question?

Tags: discussion, support

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427809/c-code-working-on-clang-xcode-not-on-g) contains code with an OP Copyright message.

I thought of removing it as it is irrelevant to the question, but well, it may have obscure legal implications, so I want to check here first.

Comment: First of all, the question should be closed as off topic until OP attempts to reduce the code to a minimal example and includes instructions to reproduce the error. Second, they can write whatever they want in there, doesn't change that they gave away the content under cc by-sa 3.0 when they posted it on SO. "Legal implications" only apply to OP if they don't have the right to post the content here; there's no implication for SO or an editor.

Comment: I'm sure neither Batman nor Robin will mind.

Comment: @l4mpi: Do you have a source for your "legal implications" assertion? Has this already been tested in the courts?

Comment: @jxh I'm not a lawyer, nor should anybody take SE comments as legal advice. But the reasoning is simple: as by the [terms and conditions (§3)](https://stackexchange.com/legal), all users license the content they post to SE under CC-BY-SA, and are of course required to have appropriate rights to grant that license to SE. That license in turn grants all users the right to edit that content. If OP doesn't have appropriate rights, then them posting to SO would be the copyright violation, not somebody else editing it as the third party isn't part to any of the copyright agreements which OP broke.

Comment: @jxh further, as long as SE does follow the DMCA procedures, I do believe they can't be held accountable either. AFAIK that one actually has been "tested in the courts", not with SE of course but with other companies that host third party content - can't give you any reference though as I'm not that interested in US copyright law. Also, I can't see the original question anymore as it was deleted, but IIRC this was a case of OP themselves attaching a copyright notice to their code, which is of course nonsense as they agreed to give it away under a CC license by posting to SE.

Comment: @l4mpi: Ok, that explains why my attempt to flag a post that contained code that had an incompatible copyright attached to it was declined. It was just a case of "not our problem to fix".

Answer (score 0):

All contributions on StackOverflow are licensed as [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), that means that everyone is free to copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format as well as to **remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose**, even commercially, however you must give proper attribution and publish the remixed content under the same license.

The bold part means we can actually edit any contribution as we want without any headache as long as we make clear who contributed what to the final outcome.

So probably (I'm not a lawyer) the used license would not forbid doing what you want to do.

Of course all this assumes that the contribution indeed belonged to the original contributor and is not a breach of copyright by itself. However some of such cases might be (people just copying code from somewhere including the copyright notices) and in these cases removal of just the copyright notices seems to be the wrong course.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you needed to answer 2 questions that ask the same thing?  Older questions can be closed as duplicates of newer questions if the newer question (and its answers) are of better quality.  I would have bountied this question if it was an option, but bounties are disabled on meta.

Comment: @cimmanon I wouldn't have answered both if I felt they were asking the same thing. This one just asks for the right to do so while you also want to know if we should do it. At least that's what I felt when reading both questions. I fear people will concentrate at your question about the "should we do it" aspect, that's why I hesitated but then decided to write a partially different answer here too that concentrates on the license discussion and leaves the "should we do it" aspect to your Q. I'm not sure if the questions should be duplicates. Didn't you too create a new Q and linked to this?

Comment: Considering my question is being closed now as a duplicate of this question, yeah, the community seems to think the questions are the same.  So, thanks.

Comment: @cimmanon It has changed. This question is closed as duplicate of yours now. I think the discussion would have been clearer if the legal implication would have been separated from the "should we do it" part, but if the community thinks it's better to discuss both in one question...