# Should copyright information be removed from code? (in questions or answers)

Tags: discussion, support, legal

Should copyright information (for code belonging to the author) attached to blocks of code be removed?  Are we legally obligated to keep these notices here?  Or can they be treated like noise (like greetings and "hope that helps!"), which can be safely removed?

```
// Created by JimBob on 3/15/16.
// Copyright ©JimBob.
// So much social media, wow!

function doStuff() {
    // the stuff you gotta do
    return true;
}
```

There is a similar question here on meta, but it never got an answer: [Copyright message in code in question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285737/copyright-message-in-code-in-question)

Comment: @Servy That question is about code where the person who posted it does not own the copyright.  I'm asking about cases where the person *does* own the copyright.

Comment: Whatever the answer is - the author is licensing the *entire* code under CC-Wiki by posting it, rendering any copyright notice in the code that contradicts CC-Wiki moot.

Comment: @Servy But what if the copyright holder doesn't want the code removed?  We, as editors, want to remove noise (which some people will consider the copyright notice).  Should we be doing that or is that breaking the copyright rules?

Comment: @cimmanon then their answer should be deleted (if there's an impasse with the user)

Comment: If all the copyright is doing at that point is serving as attribution, then CC-by-SA (which is what we're licensing under right now) is likely sufficient enough for attribution.

Comment: IANAL but, did you asked JimBob if you could use that code, and did he give you his written permission?

Comment: Plot twist: JimBob is cimmanon's sock puppet.

Comment: IANAL, but I'm pretty sure all authors of original work already have copyright the moment they created their work. CC-by-SA just specifies what must be done to license the copyrighted work. The copyright notice itself is redundant, but certainly well within the author's rights. I don't think it's noise necessarily. The `// So much social media, wow!` comment could certainly be removed :).

Comment: I'm not sure how about the license applied in SO, however, one important consequence of Copyright statements in many OpenSource license is that, e.g.,  SO can not change the license without asking the Copyright Holders for allowance.

Comment: @CAFEBABE - this was a fairly narrow case of the author of the answer also being the author of the code. No license specified, just `// (c) TheAnswerer` and other unwanted fluff

Comment: @CAFEBABE It's specifically stated in SO's policies that by posting content to the site you're implicitly licencing it to CC-by-SA.

Comment: @Servy What if I published code that was copylefted (which usually requires that you do not remove this copyright notice blah blah blah) prior to posting an answer and quote an excerpt of it as part of my answer?  Doesn't changing the license to CC-by-SA violate the previous license?

Comment: @cimmanon By posting the content to the site you're asserting that you have the right to post that content and apply the CC-by-SA licence to it.  If you don't have that right, then that content would be subject to removal by the rights holder via a DMCA takedown request.

Comment: @Pekka: you might want to read up on IP law. Under the Berne Convention, copyright exists as soon as the work in question is "fixed in tangible form". Further, *licensing* a work (as in a CC license) manifestly does **not** transfer *ownership* of the copyright: it merely allows others to *use* the work under the terms of the license.

The author still maintains the rights to his work, but depending on the terms of the CC license involved, others are allowed to (A) use the work in question and/or (B) create *derivative works* from it. Either of which might involve getting further permissions.

Comment: @Nicholas I didn't talk about transfer of Copyright, though. I just chose the wrong word - I should have said "rendering any **license terms** that contradict CC-Wiki moot".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copyright message in code in question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285737/copyright-message-in-code-in-question)

Comment: @zero298 That question didn't have any answers when I posted this question.  The guy who answered that question answered *this* question first.

Comment: @zero298 the duplicate your marked is now a duplicate of this one, you mayconsider retract close vote

Comment: @cimmanon I thought about the same. By `That question is about code where the person who posted it does not own the copyright.` do you mean sth like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038383/equivalent-set-base-query-for-the-cursor?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If it has a copyright, then it would be improper to remove it.

Everything is posted under https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing, Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike.  Stack overflow is a licensee, not the owner of the copyright, https://stackexchange.com/legal:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and **irrevocably licensed** to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.
>
> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of **another party**

You can absolutely post copyrighted material here as long as you don't violate somebody else's copyright.  That copyright still applies, but the author has licensed it to Stack Overflow (and, by extension to readers), subject to the conditions.  The copyright notice is most definitely not moot.  Attribution is required when copying under the CC share-alike license.  If the original copyright is valid, then the original poster has the right to sue for infringement if somebody copies without attribution or even removes the copyright notice.  Here's a (admittedly potentially biased) reference from a law office: http://www.photolaw.net/did-someone-remove-the-copyright-notice-from-your-photograph.html.

The CC License link at the bottom of each page also says:

> You must, unless a request has been made pursuant to Section 4(a), keep intact all copyright notices for the Work

Not much room for ambiguity there.

Comment: I like this answer. What is missing maybe is that the posted copyrighted material must be kind of compatible with the CC license, otherwise material from someone else could not also be published as CC here. (see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility) This prevents posting of many copyrighted material.

Comment: Btw. there is an interesting wording difference in the attribution. On the [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) page they link to [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) which says: "You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner" while on the attribution required page directly they quote it as "You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor". This seems to kind of contradict itself.

Comment: @Trilarion: The OP didn't ask that, but that is covered in the second part of the first quote.  The poster warrants that the material is compatible with the license.  The "Attribution required" blog is not the license, it is a human-readable page with a few issues.  Always consult the license itself if you really need to know because it is the only thing that is binding.

Comment: So what this means is that if a contributor to SO would put copyright notices all over his/her posts even multiple times they could never be edited out or it would be a violation of the CC license, since you must keep all copyright notices intact. In this case it's advisable to never remove any copyright notices from any post because either you are not allowed to do that or the whole post is a copyright theft in itself (when the material is not compatible with posting here).

Comment: Correct, but the out is that the post can be deleted if it is spam. Multiple copyright messages are probably going to be frowned on by the moderators.

Comment: Heh, I don't get why people are so hung up on this. Putting the attribution into code comments isn't much different than, say, *linking* to where the code came from and mentioning the author outside the code block, which we kind of require users to do when they copy-paste things from external sources, and frequently delete posts which blatantly ignore attribution requirements (we even have a mod message template specifically for plagiarism). We certainly don't edit that stuff out as "noise."

Comment: @animuson Where do you see people hung up on this? I for example totally admit I got it wrong the first time. Now here is a very clear answer with overwhelming upvotes. Couldn't be much clearer now.

Comment: @Trilarion The fact that people actually would have considered this as noise that should be removed confused me. We didn't need to bring legal notices into this at all to prove a point. It's pretty straight-forward that we would not remove attribution for where something came from.

Answer (score 7):

One case where you definitely **cannot** do this is where the answer is posted by someone (let's say "cimmanon"), but the copyright is to "JimBob".  If you then delete the copyright notice, then a user who is following the correct copyright rules would give attribution to "cimmanon" not "JimBob", thus violating the original copyright.

Comment: I totally have to admit that this is the case I forgot yesterday. I always assumed people who contribute either have the copyright or just link to copyrighted material. The authorship of everything that happens here is covered by the editing history and name below the contributions. It would probably be nice to kind of standardize the "JimBob" copyright notice. Especially one needs caution because the license that "JimBob" used must be compatible with publishing under CC, not every license is. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any use of code on stackoverflow, if following stackoverflow's rules and best practices, is small enough that you could rightfully claim fair use.

Fair use implies not only usage of the work, but also dissemination since another party using the work could likewise just claim fair use. Moreover fair use supersedes the need for copyright attribution; the requirement described by any license to make attribution is a burden by copyright, which is exactly what fair use alleviates.

Therefore, I suggest, for the sake of signal-to-noise, to delete the copyright information unless somehow the copyright information has inherent relevance to the programming question at hand (I can't imagine why).

Comment: I don't believe this is true. The fact that you stole only a small snippet of code does not make it "fair use." The fair use exception is designed to facilitate commentary/parody/criticism, archiving/reporting, research, teaching, and similar uses. Aside from that, even the "substantiality" doctrine doesn't necessarily apply because it considers the entirety of the work. If the provided code snippet is already small, then excerpting a small portion of it could still mean that you were copying a substantial portion of the original, which would violate the copyright.

Comment: This is a somewhat open legal debate, as this question hasn't really been tested in court (I would be willing to defend myself in court if you sue me, to find out). I would argue that the code is clearly intended for a, a constructive educational purpose, which falls under fair use.

Comment: Regarding substantiality, first of all a lot of code posted to stackoverflow is indeed a small part of a larger copyrighted work. It's true that in some questions where post their homework or their own minimal examples reproducing their problem, it's the entire work, but those works are generally owned directly by the author. And in these cases, if the author doesn't want the public to use their code as an educational resource in the future, they are misusing stackoverflow in the first place and the questions should be improved to better adhere to stackoverflow's guidelines.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I may have misinterpreted the first time around. You're saying that it is fair use to discuss the code in a Stack Overflow answer. Yeah, I'd say you're probably right, that falls under research/education exception to fair use. I was thinking of using a portion of the code from a Stack Overflow answer in your own application. That would not necessarily be fair use (likely not). And that would be where the copyright information is important.

Comment: Yes.  In last case, attribution is required.  And, that's another reason not to remove the message.  Just because it doesn't apply to you in your FAIR USE for research doesn't mean that you can post it without attribution or copyright: When you repost it, you are granting a creative commons share-alike license.  Fair use does not give the authority to grant licenses.  Maybe you could publish it in a trade journal that doesn't require the granting of a license, but not here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure this is a dissenting view, but I think it's more likely that the author will actually get credited in the average drive-by-user's codebase if the copyright information is already in the snippet. I mean, really... how many unregistered viewers are reading the CC-Wiki link and including a link to the post or the author's SO user profile?

I like people getting credit for what they've done. To that end, I probably wouldn't remove that type of comment. The syntax highlighting for comments already serves to make that information appear more subdued.

Legality aside, I hope this is a consideration.

Comment: The second part of the original question is specifically "do we have the legal right to do so?" - which would seem to be Trilarion's answer.  Whether it's a good thing to do is a slightly different question perhaps?

Comment: @canon Why leaving it to chance. To have a kind of level playing field I would say that then every code contribution should have an additional comment field automatically inserted naming the author. This would clearly make it even more likely that the authors will actually get credited in the average drive-by-user's codebase. But I think the license itself doesn't require anything of it.

Comment: This question already silently asserts that if it's legal to remove, we should remove it. I think it's good that you answered here rather than asking a new question. I don't agree, but I'm glad you posted it, it's a point worth raising.

Comment: @canon: Of course, an automatically-inserted comment raises the effect of wrong language-inference from bad highlighting to broken code.  Which is ok, it'll be obvious when the language is wrong and most cases will be quickly fixed, leading also to better highlighting.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse: The question particularly asks "Should copyright be removed?" and not just "It is permitted to do so?"

Comment: @hdv Well, we already have a policy that encourages the removal of noise/fluff.  If the copyright information *is* noise, the logical next step is to remove it.  The motivation behind my question is a case where the copyright information for code in an answer was removed by someone else.

Comment: @cimmanon The question asks "It is noisy, but do we have the legal right to do so?", presenting "It is noisy" as a fact. This answer challenges that by saying it's not noisy, but useful. Based on your comment, I now get the impression you hadn't intended to present "It is noisy" as a fact, is that correct?

Comment: @hvd I do feel that copyright notices can be noisy, but that doesn't mean it is OK to remove them if they must be there for legal reasons.

Answer (score -2):

All contributions on StackOverflow are licensed as [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), that means that everyone is free to copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format as well as to **remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose**, even commercially, however you must give proper attribution and publish the remixed content under the same license.

The bold part means we can actually edit any contribution as we want without any headache as long as we make clear who contributed what to the final outcome.

Removing copyright notices from code is a specific example of an edit but in this context they are by no means special - the license treats all possible edits exactly the same. The copyright owner of the original contribution is clearly displayed by the web site even without any notices in the contribution itself.

These copyright notices do not add any value in understanding the question or answer, however they distract from the issue, therefore editing the issue and removing them seems appropriate, although I'm not a 100% decided on that one. I would also be happy with a single comment line (automatically inserted) at each code block mentioning the author and containing a link to the contribution.

Of course all this assumes that the contribution indeed belonged to the original contributor and is not a breach of copyright by itself.

I searched a bit for more examples using this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/451262/search-for-copyright-notices-in-posts) which gives also a lot of false positives.

- [flvFPW1() - What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378117/flvfpw1-what-does-it-do/378243#378243) Answer is: "Google yields // Copyright 2002, Marja Ribbers-de Vroed, FlevOOware ([www.flevooware.nl/dreamweaver/"](http://www.flevooware.nl/dreamweaver/%22) - This could actually hint to a potential copyright problem. Just copying code from somewhere including copyright notices can be dangerous. Just removing the copyright notice would be unwise.
- [How do you store uploaded files in a filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225088/how-do-you-store-uploaded-files-in-a-filesystem/225112#225112) "/// 
  /// Class for generating storage structure and file names for document storage.
  /// Copyright (c) 2008, Huagati Systems Co.,Ltd.
  /// " - The same case. This might be a potential breach of copyright by the poster.
- [multimap in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380595/multimap-in-net/380601#380601) The author himself (Frans Bouma) publishes code which is from himself and under BSD. Unfortunately this is invalid as the [comment by Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319031/should-copyright-information-be-removed-from-code-in-questions-or-answers/319046?noredirect=1#comment322541_319031) already mentioned because if it is CC-BY-SA the copyright notice can be removed at any time while if it is BSD it must not be removed. But because the author can of course dual license he licensed it under CC-BY-SA and printed 22 meaningless lines of text additionally.

Comment: @canon It means that they are one special element of the set of possible edits but in the context of this question it doesn't matter because the license treats all modifications of licensed content exactly the same, so there is nothing special about them. I made it more clear.

Comment: @canon: He means "a specific example of an edit".

Comment: If you remove a copyright notice from code an SO user was not entitled to post, how are you **not** contributing to copyright theft?  Self-appointed editors do not have any more right to do that than anyone else, whatever SO's Ts&Cs are.

Comment: "the license treats all modifications of licensed content exactly the same"  deftly overlooking the point that copyright material included without permission is not "licensed" by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @MartynA IANAL but I thought SO is okay as long as they only follow the DMCA requests. How can anyone know that by editing anything they are "contributing" to copyright theft? Once copyrighted material imcompatible with the CC license is on SO, the damage is already done. But the idea of DMCA is that SO cannot and must not control everything.

Comment: @MartynA "deftly overlooking the point" please see my previous comment and the "Of course all this assumes that the contribution indeed belonged to the original contributor" provision in the answer as well as the first two examples I found. So I return the compliment.

Comment: "How can anyone know that by editing anything they are "contributing" to copyright theft?"  By removing a copyright notice, they most certainly are contributing fo copyright theft, regardless of whether they think editing for SO gives them some special immunity to the law.

Comment: @MartyA Maybe. I think you should flesh that out as an answer.

Comment: They *are* special edits and removing copyright notices is specifically prohibited.  Read the license in detail.