# Can I retroactively dual license code I posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, licensing

*Edited the question to only contain the part which is not being answered by the linked question*

I know it is possible to [dual license](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291319/is-it-valid-if-one-licenses-their-own-answer-at-stack-overflow) code posted on Stack Overflow.

Does this also apply retroactively to code which was posted before adding the license text to one's user profile?

Comment: Was it [Can someone replicate Stack Overflow if all users put their posted content under e.g. CC0?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411285/11682469)

Comment: I don't think licensing is something you need to worry about when answering on SO. It's not like SO is going to sue someone for using code they copy-pasted from an answer...

Comment: If you *did* add an additional licence note that the user only has to abide to the licenses of the post at the time they used it. Adding a licence that *might* require additional restrictions on them would not be enforceable if they used that solution 9 years ago.

Comment: @Cerbrus No, but by using a more permissive license it can mean that people don't need to reference the original post/credit the author, it's a convenience for copiers more than anything (Assuming people are actually following the licensing requirements of course).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it valid if one licenses their own answer at Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291319/is-it-valid-if-one-licenses-their-own-answer-at-stack-overflow)

Comment: Does anyone _actually_ attribute all the code they copy from SO? What if they don't? What if they write a line that happens to be identical to one on SO? Small snippets of code aren't practically copyright-able.

Comment: @Cerbrus I do :) So.. someone does. Unless it's something trivial and/or used everywhere, like `int i = 0;`

Comment: @Cerbrus I do.... but that's only so I can find it again later on :p and my attribution consists entirely of a link to the post

Comment: @Scratte: What's "trivial"? Where's the line? My point here is: Why worry about legal implications on a theoretical problem that's practically impossible to occur?

Comment: @Cerbrus To me, trivial is when it's something that I do all the time or that is reoccurring in all the documentation. Like boilerplate. I never attribute that. When I'm in doubt, I'm more inclined to attribute it. It keeps me not worrying and as Nick also said, it makes it easy to find the source again.

Comment: @Cerbrus they likely refer to the legal concept of trivial code. See [What is defined as trivial code when licensing a project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5061) for an example. There is no exact line to be drawn - it is determined on a case-by-case basis

Comment: @Scratte / Oleg: All I'm seeing there is that there's no real definition of "trivial"... Even that one answer Oleg linked already contains __3 different definitions of trivial__ code. Again, unless you're working for a huge multinational and you're taking "inspiration" from another huge company's code (How'd you even get access to that?), I really wouldn't worry too much. Now consider you're just copying some lines from SO... I'm not saying you _shouldn't_ attribute it if you wanna, but you're not getting into trouble if you don't.

Comment: @Cerbrus oh, no, no, that's not to say that one should worry about copying trivial amounts of code, just as a reply to your "what's 'trivial'". There is definitely no *fixed* definition of what's trivial. This more of a practical question - but the legal concept does exist

Comment: Then I'll TL;DR my practical opinion: __"Don't worry, be happy!"__

Comment: I'm not worried about getting into trouble with others. I'm worried about not doing what I feel is the right thing to do. I may be able to get away with stuff, but I don't want to go there when it's so easy not to. It's just a comment in my code, and an added attribution on a list. On the legal side, I'd think [Google’s 9 lines](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/) were trivial. Apparently, they're not.

Comment: On an off-note to the OP: yes, you are dree to dual/triple/quadruple license all the work you have *provided the new license does not violate CC-BY-SA* (also might be worth looking at what SE previously employed - there were a couple of debacles about forced relicensing in the past). In general, this means that you can apply a *more permissive* license, but not a less permissive one. When you post the same thing somewhere else - this is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @OlegValter You _can_ apply a less permissive one, but people will always have the option to use CC BY-SA. You can offer as many licensing options as you want, and the person who wants to use the code can pick which one they wish to use.

Comment: As I said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401995/feature-request-automatic-insertion-of-license-header-for-code-blocks#comment801806_401995), Creative Commons recommend against using Creative Commons licenses for software. We use CC-BY-SA licenses here because Stack Overflow posts are effectively a form of documentation that (may) contain code samples. They are *not* intended to be a primary software distribution mechanism.

Comment: @RyanM that's why I said "in general" :) In any case, it is impossible to "truly" apply a more restrictive license once one posted on Stacks since they agreed to CC-BY-SA in the first place, so yeah, what you said - it won't stop others from using Stack's CC-BY-SA

Comment: @JeanneDark While the linked question answers *how* one can dual license, it does not explicitly mention if this applies to code published in the past, which is the main concern of my question

Comment: Another off-note about one of your previous revisions. Your legal department is not overly cautious, they are, strictly speaking, *correct*. Note the last 2 bytes of "CC-BY-SA": SA means "Share Alike" which explicitly requires "you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original". However unlikely it is that the company will ever be found guilty of infringing on that clause, the legal department has a valid concern to protect everyone against.

Comment: @TimMeyer The question linked by JeanneDark does, in fact, answer your question. To be specific, [Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) in [the top voted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291323/3773011) says "The copyright of the content always remains with the author and they can re-license anything they publish on Stack Overflow any way they choose in parallel to SO", which covers your question.

Comment: @TimMeyer The part of your question which is "Does this also apply retroactively" is unanswerable, because it depends on what *you* write as the grant of an additional license (i.e. you could write it such that it did or did not apply to posts you've already made, or even a subset of those). For example, a user could say "Everything I, a.k.a <username>, posted on SE after 2021-08-31T00:00UTC is additionally licensed under <enter the additional license here>", or just "Everything I, a.k.a <username>, post or have posted on SE is additionally licensed under <enter the additional license here>".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Yes

Licensing your code to Stack Overflow under CC BY-SA doesn't take away any of *your* rights: it only grants rights to other people.  One of your rights is the right to license your code to others.  You are free to do so under any license, at any time—there's no need for it to be when you originally posted it.

Of course, your code is still *also* available under the CC BY-SA license.  Providing the code under an additional license allows the person using it to choose which license they use it under.

Answer (score 4):

Deep in the [legal text](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing)
(*Subscriber Content*), it says that by posting here your content “is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis”.

What this means is you have only *licensed* your content here under CC BY-SA: you still own the content. You are free to release your content under other licenses (even by republishing elsewhere: that is the “non-exclusive” part). 
Many people choose to add a license to their content by saying so in their profile.

Comment: You are not free, therefore, to offer your code somewhere else with an "exclusive" license.